# ActiveRecord - associating foreign keys with different naming conventions?

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

I am working on a private messaging system using PHP-ActiveRecord ORM. I have models called 'User' and 'Message', MySQL tables called 'users' and 'messages', and in the messages table, I have fields called 'sender_id' and 'recipient_id'. However, I have no idea how to properly associate senders and recipients to the User model.

This is what I have so far in the User model:

```
static $has_many = array(
    array('messages'),
    array('recipients', 'foreign_key' => 'recipient_id', 'class_name' => 'Message'),
    array('senders', 'foreign_key' => 'sender_id', 'class_name' => 'Message'),
);
```

and this is what I have so far in the Message model:

```
static $belongs_to = array(
    array('sender', 'class_name' => 'User'),
    array('recipient', 'class_name' => 'User'),
);
```

However, when I run the code such as $message->recipient->first_name, it does not properly pull the first name from the User model, like I want it to. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Normally, I just use the standard naming conventions. However, for this example, we have to have sender_id and recipient_id, which are both the same type, so I can't just use the standard naming conventions as I have been doing.

Any help would be highly appreciated. I am using the PHP-ActiveRecord ORM. I think the Rails version is more widely used, but it is my understanding that they work the same except with different syntax.

Comment: no worries... For the future, you don't have to accept answer to every question you ask, just the ones that provide a proper solution to your question

Answer (score 1):

You also need to specify the foreign keys in the $belong_to, otherwise they will be inferred from the table's name (i.e. `user_id`):

```
static $belongs_to = array(
   array('sender', 'class_name' => 'User', 'foreign_key' => 'sender_id'),
   array('recipient', 'class_name' => 'User', 'foreign_key' => 'recipient_id'),
);
```